# Insert data to a table in mysql database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, insert, mysql-python

i'm trying to insert my data to mysql db it don't give me any Error but it send null data instead of my data to db table.
i can't find why it doesn't run correctly.
this is the snippet code:

```
import mysql.connector
import re



def insert_to_db (user_name, password):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect (user='root', password='Alora36318', host='localhost', database='Alora')

    cursor = cnx.cursor ()

    cursor.execute ('INSERT INTO email_address VALUES (user_name, password)')

    cnx.commit ()

    cnx.close()

def add_data ():
    regex_email = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
    regex_names = '^[a-zA-Zا-ی]'

    user_name = input ("Enter Your Email Address: ")
    password = input ("Enter Your Password: ")

    def check_email(email):
        if (re.search(regex_email, email)):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    if not check_email(user_name):
        print ("Error", "This Email Is Not A Valid Email")
        print ("Correct form: example@email.com")
        add_data ()
    else:
        insert_to_db (user_name, password)
        print ('Successfuly Inserted to DB!', user_name, password)
        add_data ()


add_data ()
```

Comment: What does the structure of your database look like?

Comment: user_name       |       password                                                                                                     Null                   |       Null                                                                                                        Null                   |       Null

Comment: That is not the structure of your database!  What is the definition of the table into which you are trying to insert the data?  How have you defined the fields of the table?  What is the table key, are there any foreign keys, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a bigginer so I asked this funny Question But for bigginers this is the answer:

make a connection:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect (host = 'localhost', database = 'databasename', user = 'username', password = 'password')
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

make sure that you have table in database:

```
table_creation = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (value_name1 value_type1, value_name2 value_type2, value_name3 value_type3)"""
cursor.execute (table_creation)
conn.commit()
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

then make insert text for table:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO table_name (value_name1, value_name2, value_name3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""
```

put the values that can be a string, numeric, int, bool, date or name of variable with any data type and send them to table:

```
val = (value1, value2, value3)
cursor.execute(sql, val)
conn.commit()
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

then close your connection:

```
cursor.close()
```

thats all and very simple, for more information check the document of mysql.